# Contracted form of Present Continuous with nouns ending with -s

Tags: present-continuous, contractions, third-person-singular

How do we form the contracted form of Present Continuous with nouns ending with -s, for example:

```
Thomas is playing football next Sunday.
```

Can we write

```
Thomas' playing football next Sunday.
```

How does this form function in oral language? For example, can we say like

```
['tɒmǝs 'pleɪɪŋ 'fʊtbɔ:l ...]
```

instead of

```
['tɒmǝs ɪz 'pleɪɪŋ 'fʊtbɔ:l ...]
```

I did research in Google but it seems that most instructions deal with very basic grammar, for instance, how to contract I am (I'm) or you are (you're).

Comment: We can say "He's playing football" or "John's playing football", but because 'Thomas' ends with an 's', we would pronounce 'is' as a separate syllable.

Comment: @KateBunting And in writing we would also use the full form - "Thomas is playing..." - wouldn't we?

Comment: I hesitated about whether or not to suggest that it could be written as "Thomas's". I think it could be if you were quoting spoken dialogue.